# why is this set NOT open?? (regarding uniform convergence topology)

Tags: general-topology

Let $$B([0,1[,R) := \{ f:[0,1[ \rightarrow R:\ f \text{ is a bounded function}\}.$$

Let $$A = \{f: [0,1[ \rightarrow R:\ f\text{ is bounded such that } f(x)<1\text{ for all }x\in [0,1[\}.$$

Considering the topology of uniform convergence, I've proven that $A$ is not closed: The constant function $f(x)=1$ is adherent to $A$ but not in $A$.

But how come is it not open? Can you show me a function in $A$ that's not interior to $A$?

Just to remember, for each $g\in B([0,1[,R)$ and $r > 0$ the neighborhoods are as follows:

$$V(g,r) = \{f\in B([0,1[,R):\ |f(x)-g(x)|< r,\text{ for all }x\in [0,1[\}.$$

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x)=x$. Notice that if you allow for a band of width $r$ then you will allow for functions that go beyond $1$.